# Word splitting using multiple IFS

Tags: bash, split, cpu-word, ifs

Being new to shell scripting, I am not clear about the Quoting and splitting concepts in bash. In the below snippet:

```
array1=("france-country":"Italy-country":"singapore-country")
echo ${#array1[@]}

IFS=":-"

for i in ${array1[@]}
do
       echo "$i"
done
unset IFS
```

with IFS being `:-`, I thought the result would be:

```
france-country
Italy-country
belgium-country
```

as I had quoted them("france-country"). I think it should not get split on "-". But the results were:

```
france
country
Italy
country
belgium
country
```

It would be great if someone can point me out my mistake in understanding.

Comment: Why are you having "-" in IFS if you dont want to split on hyphen. Just remove it?

Answer (score 0):

For your problem you can simply change the field separator as `:` i.e. `IFS=:` because each country name is separated by `:` not `:-` in your example

```
array1=("france-country":"Italy-country":"singapore-country")
echo ${#array1[@]}

IFS=":"

for i in ${array1[@]}
do
       echo "$i"
done
unset IFS
```

FYI, array elements in bash are separated by `space` so the whole string `"france-country":"Italy-country":"singapore-country"` is a single element of the array therefore `echo ${#array1[@]}` will always be `1` . So I do not see any use of an array in this example. Simple variable would have been suffice.

Answer (score 0):

This script shows how to split a colon-separated string into a Bash array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

words="france-country:Italy-country:singapore-country:Australia-country"

IFS=':' array1=($words)
numwords="${#array1[@]}"

for((i=0; i<numwords; i++));do
    echo "$i: ${array1[i]}"
done
```

**output**

```
0: france-country
1: Italy-country
2: singapore-country
3: Australia-country
```

Note that in

```
array1=($words)
```

we don't put quotes around `$words`, as that would prevent word splitting.

We don't actually need the quotes in

```
words="france-country:Italy-country:singapore-country:Australia-country"
```

but quotes (either single or double) *would* be needed if there were any spaces in that string. Similarly, the quotes are superfluous in `numwords="${#array1[@]}"`, and many Bash programmers would omit them because we know the result of `${#array1[@]}` will never have spaces in it.

It's a Good Idea to always use quotes in Bash unless you're *sure* you don't want them, eg in the case of `array1=($words)` above, or when performing tests with the `[[` ... `]]` syntax.

I suggest you bookmark [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) and browse through their FAQ. But the only way to *really* learn the arcane ways of quoting and splitting in Bash is to to write *lots* of scripts. :)

You may also find [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) helpful.